# expression of multiple objects/elements from a list

Tags: r, list, regression

I am learning `R` and have the following question. I ran the following code to find the best polynomial model.

```
set.seed(123)
library(ISLR)

#####################################
# polynomial
rss <- rep(NA, 15)
fits <- list()
for (i in 1:15) {
    fits[[i]] <- lm(mpg ~ poly(displacement, i), data = Auto)
    rss[i] <- deviance(fits[[i]])
}
rss

anova(fits[[1]], fits[[2]], fits[[3]], fits[[4]], fits[[5]], fits[[6]], fits[[7]], fits[[8]], fits[[9]], fits[[10]], fits[[11]], fits[[12]], fits[[13]], fits[[14]], fits[[15]])
```

The code works. But the last part about `ANOVA()` definitely seems tedious and not practical if fits contains large number of elements. How to simplify it?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to turn a list of values into separate paramers, you use `do.call`. So for your example you would run

```
do.call("anova", fits)
```